# is Shopify web checkout allowed inside iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store, shopify, checkout

I integrated Shopify web checkout into my iOS app and i am curious if Apple allows showing a webview modal **inside** app to handle checkout.

Thanks !

Comment: Without any more details on your product, the answer is "maybe". Depends on what you are selling (e.g. physical vs virtual). Have a look at chapter `3.1 Payments` of the `App Store Review Guidelines`, includes in-depth descriptions as well as common use cases.

Comment: thanks @nathan for the comment, i will be selling physical goods, which i think is OK for Apple according to Itay's answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> 3.1.3(e) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase physical goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.

So, if you are selling physicals goods or services, it should be ok

Comment: Thanks @Itay for your answer, we will be selling physical goods and they will be consumed out of the app, which means everything looks fine but of course this is Apple "trust but wait until approval" :)

Comment: Don’t worry, Apple usually follows this rule, they shouldn’t make any problem for you. They might ask what are you selling on the review but you can prove you sell a physical good, it is totally fine.